# How to insert data from one table to another with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I am trying to insert new rows into `table a` and *partially* load the rows with data from `table b`. I would only like to insert new rows where the field `b.id` is not present in the `a.id` column.

**Here are my tables:**

```
table_a       table_b
---------     -----------
id             id
first_name     first_name
country        middle_name
last_name      last_name
```

**Here is my code:**

```
INSERT INTO table_a a
SELECT b.id, b.first_name,b. last_name
FROM table_b b WHERE b.id <> a.id
```

**The Question:** How can I do this using an insert select statement? Please note, I've included middle name in one table and Country in another table to make this more comparable to my current situation. Is there a way to "map" the fields? or must I ensure that my insert select statement has the exact same number of values to insert as the target table? Or will it just look for matching column names and only update those columns that match?

Comment: I've made an update to the question to hone in on exactly my issue - can I set the fields to be equal to one another or must I include the exact number of values with quotes for blank values? `..,'',..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would only like to insert new rows **where the field b.id is not present** in the a.id column.

an alternative solution would be using `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL`

```
INSERT INTO table_a
SELECT  b.*
FROM    table_b b
        LEFT JOIN table_a a
            ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   a.ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/792d4/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can do following, check if  id exists in table_a

```
INSERT INTO table_a (id, first_name, last_name)
SELECT b.id, b.first_name,b.last_name
FROM table_b b
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM table_a a WHERE b.id = a.id)
```

Your country column will be null for all the rows. If you want to store static value then query should be

```
INSERT INTO table_a (id, first_name, country, last_name)
SELECT b.id, b.first_name, 'USA', b.last_name
FROM table_b b
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM table_a a WHERE b.id = a.id)
```

Comment: I've made an update to the question to hone in on exactly my issue - can I set the fields to be equal to one another or must I include the exact number of values with quotes for blank values? `..,'',..`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
   INSERT INTO table_a a (id , first_name , last_name) Values (
                SELECT b.id, b.first_name,b.last_name
                FROM table_b b WHERE  a.id not in (select id from table_b) )
```

Comment: I've made an update to the question to hone in on exactly my issue - can I set the fields to be equal to one another or must I include the exact number of values with quotes for blank values? `..,'',..`

Comment: the field which u dont update it will be automatically null or empty like country